# Data Annotation to start with specific ID in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a simple Id in my model like this:

```
   [AutoIncrement]
   public Int32 Id { get; set; }
```

It auto-increments whenever a new record is inserted, but it always begins with 0. What if I wanted to make it begin with 10000? I would like to set a default starting ID. Any way to do this through data annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not available via an attribute, each RDBMS has their own syntax for resetting the AutoIncrement, e.g. for SQL Server:

```
db.ExecuteSql("DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 10000)");
```

Comment: I can handle with this. Thanks!